# Remove a class in all nested a elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

This would be simple but I am stuck. How can I remove all hidden classes in nested a elements in the list without using a loop?

```
<ul class="hello">
  <li><a class="hidden">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="">test 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="hidden">test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

So it would show test 1, test 2, test 3.

Comment: You mean using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Did you try $(".hidden").removeClass("hidden"); with JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*without using a loop*" seems your are looking for some JavaScript / jQuery solution.

You can use following code:

```
jQuery('.hello a').removeClass('hidden');
```

```js
jQuery('.hello a').removeClass('hidden');
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="hello">
  <li><a class="hidden">test 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="">test 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="hidden">test 3</a></li>
</ul>
```